# Vim not displaying the letter 'l'

Tags: macos, vim

```
PATH="/usr/loca /bin:/usr/loca /sbin:~/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH"
PATH=$PATH:~/bin:/usr/loca /mysq /bin
```

When I open text files in vim, all the letters `l` do not get displayed. When I copy and paste from there it does show up so I don't know how this could happen. Any ideas where to begin looking?

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot?

Comment: The pattern is: "l/" is replaced by " /" for some reason. What plugins/bundles do you use? What is your ~/.vimrc?

Comment: Hi EarlGray, TY for the quick response. I am on a mac OS 10.6 using vim version 7.2.108 (/usr/bin/vim). I think I tried installing some syntax highlighting color schemes before but it was a while back. Not sure what else I did. Where do I check for plugins again for vim? My ~/.vimrc is not present

Comment: @user530361 Have you installed any vim plugins? Is it just a fresh installed vim?
Also, the problem may be related to auto-correction abbreviations, could you show output of ":ab"?

Comment: @EarlGray abbreviations wouldn't affect text already in a file.  And if it was with text being entered the problem would also be present when the text was copied and pasted elsewhere.

Comment: @user530361 Do you have syntax highlight on? Try ":syntax off", maybe it's just a messed up highlight scheme which conceals some characters. But it's very hard to guess.

Comment: No abbreviation found when running :ab. Yes I tried syntax highlighting off still no luck. I remember I did mess around with trying to install version control highlighting plugin in the past I cant remember what I did to screw it up though. I think this vim came with the OS installation. The problem happens on any files old or new.

Comment: You can check for installed plugins in `~/.vim/plugin/`, for installed syntax schemes in `~/.vim/syntax`, for vimscripts executed automatically at vim's start in `~/.vim/autoload`.

Comment: Funny thing i dont have a ~/.vim dir. Is there another location for vim files?

Comment: @user530361 ~/.vim directory is a hidden one. I'd recommend typing `vim ~/.vim` in Terminal, if vim creates a new file, there's no such directory, otherwise it will display list of files in it. Or, rather, try executing `cd ~/.vim` in vim ifself.

Comment: sone$ cd ~/.vim
-bash: cd: /Users/sone/.vim: No such file or directory. :(

Comment: I'm sorry this might be another problem. I do a ll and get a directory listing and there is still missing 'l' letters in the output

Comment: @user530361 try using a different font. The one you're using might have bad kerning or ligature information for the `l/` combination.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am using profont and it doesnt display the letter l in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to this happened to me today in OSX Mountain Lion. I installed the ProFont 2.2 font package and set my terminal to use it, and all of a sudden any instance of l/ that was printed on my terminal became invisible. This lead to hilarity such as a /usr/loca bin/ directory in my path; the characters were still there, merely hidden.  I had to switch back to a default font to fix it.